# Javascript Array won't sort

Tags: javascript

The following code won't sort any ideas?

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var splitString = str.split(" ");
  var lengths = [];
  for(var i= 0; i< splitString.length; i++){
    lengths += splitString[i].length;
  }
  lengths.sort(function(a,b){return b-a;});
  return lengths;
}
findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: `array += integer` probably doesn't do what you think it does. Also, your function tries to return an array of word lengths, not the longest word as its name suggests.

Comment: `lengths.push(splitString[i].length)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to push the length, not to add to the array.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
    var splitString = str.split(" ");
    var lengths = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
        lengths.push(splitString[i].length);
        //     ^^^^^^                     ^
    }
    lengths.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a; });
    return lengths;
}
console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Array concatenation doesn't work like that in JavaScript. You want:

```
lengths.push(splitString[i].length)
```

---

When asking questions please be specific, e.g., "won't sort" is not diagnostic.

Be explicit regarding errors (e.g., the console warning about `lengths.sort` not being a function).

The error message would lead you to ask:

- Oh, why isn't it?
- What's `lengths` when I try to call `sort` on it?
- Oh, it's not an array. I wonder why not?

Because JavaScript.

Noticing and diagnosing errors is an important skill. For trivial issues like this, the console is your best friend, because it lets you try things out a piece at a time.